# Regex that find a expression start and end with same word and separated by 10 characters

Tags: regex

My question is about a regex that find a expression starts and ends with same word and separated by 10 characters.

I've tried this regex

```
\b(\w).{1,10}(\s\1)\b
```

to solve my problem but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: please provide sample input and expected output in the question.

Comment: `(\w)` is only one character, try `(\w+)` instead.

Comment: Also, `{1,10}` means 1-10 characters, not exactly 10. Note that even `\s` is a character. So be more concise about what characters you need to be inbetween.

Comment: @AD7six in the sentence  "i want i to be me to learn something" regex would match "i want i" and "to be me to"

Comment: Try `\b(\w+)\b.{0,10}\b\1\b`.

Comment: @spayt don't tell "me" - please edit the question :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\b(\w+)\b.{0,10}\b\1\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VhjtuP/1). Mind that in many programming environments, backslashes are used as part of string escape sequences and thus needs doubling in regular string literals.

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group #1: one or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.{0,10}` - zero to ten chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\b\1\b` - same whole word as in Group 1.